# Can we use Id token to access webapi

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am totally confused with id token and access token. 
I saw in many articles saying access token can be used to call webapi but can we use id token aswell to call and authenticate webapi

Answer (score 2):

You should not use id token to access a protected Web API.

[ID Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) should be used to get information about a user - it should not be used for authorization in place of an access token.

[Access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) enable clients to securely call APIs protected by Azure.

Note that Access tokens are signed (and might get encrypted), whereas ID tokens are not.

Comment: Can we get user alias from access token?

Comment: You should not crack-open an access token (it might be encrypted in the future), but you can request both the access token and the id token.

If you really want to get the claims from the access token, see the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt nuget package which contains a [JwtSecurityToken](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityToken.cs) class which will decode the token (provided you have passed information about the STS), and expose the claims

Comment: @Chandrasekhar  Or you could use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to parse the id token or access token, then you could find the username, email or phone in the tokens.